# How do I write a "selective" Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

noob question here.

I have a directory with a lot of .c files, they're basicely libc functions that I code myself as an exercice.

I write a little main() in these files to test the functions, and I want to write a Makefile that allow me to compile only the file I want to test, for exemple:

```
make memset.c
```

And get only the executable of the code wrote in memset.c.

I tried to do something like this:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

all : %.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@
```

But obviously it doens't work. I don't what to put in place of the "all".
I know it's very basic, but I didn't manage to do it, and I did research but didn't find an answer to this specific question.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The makefile is fine. The argument to `make` should be the resulting file you want, not the source file, so `make memset.o`.

Comment: The poster doesn't want to build a `.o`, they want to build an executable.  If you want to create an executable from a same-named `.c` file you don't have to write any rules: make already has built-in rules that will do it.  Just use `make memset` to build the `memset` executable from the `memset.c` file.  Remember that you should specify _targets_ on the make command line (that is, the things you want to be built), not _sources_.  Make always starts with the target and works back to the sources, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `make -n -p` you get a dump of all of the built-in rules in make. In GNU Make 4.1, this includes:

```
%: %.o
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

So you might just needs a `%` in your makefile where you currently have `all`.

You also might find that you don't need those rules which are already built in. Suppose you have three C files, each with a `main()` as you specify: `abs.c`, `div.c` and `fmax.c`. Your Makefile needs to be no more than two lines:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
all: abs div fmax
```

which would then allow you to do `make abs` to make the `abs` executable, and `make all` to make them all.

Answer (score 1):

You can define [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) to build the object files and the executables and then invoke make with the name of the executable you want as the goal:

```
CC     = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
EXE := $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRC))

.PHONY: all obj

all: $(EXE)

obj: $(OBJ)

$(EXE): %: %.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(OBJ): %.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(EXE)
```

Then:

```
$ make memset.o
```

builds only `memset.o`,

```
$ make memset
```

builds only `memset` (and `memset.o` if needed),

```
$ make obj
```

builds all object files,

```
$ make # or make all
```

builds all executables (and object files if needed), and

```
$ make clean
```

deletes all executables and object files.

Answer (score 0):

With `wildcard`, you can achieve what you want.

Note that if each program depends on only one `.c` file, you don't need `%.o` rules:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

SRC  := $(wildcard *.c)
EXEC = $(SRC:%.c=%)

all: $(EXEC)

%: %.c
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

And just invoke this way for instance:

```
make memset
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have most you to compile the executable selectively:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@
% : %.o
    $(CC) $(LDLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Then you just need to call make with the target you want, the executable:

```
make select
```

If you have several sets of executable with different flags, you can use:

```
EX0 = drink clean
${EXE0}: % : %.o
        $(CC) $(LDLAGS) -lwater $< -o $@
EX1 = burn melt
{EX1}: % : %.o
        $(CC) $(LDLAGS) -lfire  $< -o $@
```